# python - add indicator for 10 most recent dates

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python, and I have data with a team name and dates of games that have been played, it looks something like this (except there are a few hundred rows):

```
      team    date
0     TOR     2016/10/15
1     LAK     2016/10/20
2     CGY     2016/11/03
3     BUF     2016/10/30
4     PIT     2016/10/27
5     CHI     2016/11/05
6     VAN     2016/10/20
7     BUF     2016/10/16
8     STL     2016/10/13
9     BUF     2016/10/29
10    MIN     2016/10/29
11    PIT     2016/11/05
12    CHI     2016/10/18
13    BOS     2016/10/29
14    PIT     2016/10/20
15    COL     2016/10/20
16    MTL     2016/10/20
17    MTL     2016/11/05
18    BOS     2016/11/03
19    EDM     2016/11/05
20    NSH     2016/11/01
```

I would like to add indicator columns to show which are the most recent 10 games for each team, as well as the most recent 5 games for each team. With a 1 if they are in this group, and a 0 if they are not.

I'm stumped. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your desired output, and what code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest.html) with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for selecting indices by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
#in real data use nsmallest(10)
idx = df.groupby('team')['date'].nsmallest(2).index.get_level_values(1)
df['indicator'] = np.where(df.index.isin(idx), 1, 0)

print (df)
   team       date  indicator
0   TOR 2016-10-15          1
1   LAK 2016-10-20          1
2   CGY 2016-11-03          1
3   BUF 2016-10-30          0
4   PIT 2016-10-27          1
5   CHI 2016-11-05          1
6   VAN 2016-10-20          1
7   BUF 2016-10-16          1
8   STL 2016-10-13          1
9   BUF 2016-10-29          1
10  MIN 2016-10-29          1
11  PIT 2016-11-05          0
12  CHI 2016-10-18          1
13  BOS 2016-10-29          1
14  PIT 2016-10-20          1
15  COL 2016-10-20          1
16  MTL 2016-10-20          1
17  MTL 2016-11-05          1
18  BOS 2016-11-03          1
19  EDM 2016-11-05          1
20  NSH 2016-11-01          1
```

Comment: `ARI` team is not in sample, do you think last row `NSH` team? Output is wrong? Where are 0 for top2?

Comment: So I just tried this, looking for the top 2, and here is what I got for one team:
```
      team   date                last2
17  ARI     2016-11-01     1
49  ARI     2016-11-03     0
29  ARI     2016-10-15     1
21  ARI     2016-10-27     1
41  ARI     2016-11-04     0
16  ARI     2016-10-25     0
31  ARI     2016-10-21     1
34  ARI     2016-10-29     1
35  ARI     2016-10-20     0
40  ARI     2016-10-18     1
41  ARI     2016-10-23     0
```
I should have mentioned that the index of this table is nonsense. I have since deleted it.

Comment: What I posted in my original question was a sample output of 20 rows, just to give an idea of what it looks like. In reality, there are 350 rows. NSH had similar output to ARI.

Comment: Ya, there is problem yuor index is not unique (what is necessary) - need before my code reset index by `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Glad can help you.